# MySql ORDER BY ID , but with exception

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I've an app that load some result from a mysql database. I'm doing this connection with php using this query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$intLimit)
```

and this is ok.

Now i want the same query but for example i want that the object with id = 7000 stays on top.

i tried:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY id WHEN id = '7000' then 0 else 1 LIMIT ".$intLimit)
```

but this query return nothing.

how solve it? Thanks

**EDIT 1**

using this:

```
SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY case when id = '7000' then 0 else 1 end
```

the result is 7000, 6999, 6998... without showing the new question

but i want something like 7000, 7100, 7099, 7098...

Comment: why down vote?... i love this people that leaves a down vote without comment...

Comment: `Cocoa error 3840` isn't an error that would be generated by either PHP or MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even skip the WHEN construct and simply state the primary ordering criterion as `ID=7000 DESC` and the secondary as `ID`

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY ID=7000 DESC, ID DESC LIMIT ...
```

Comment: changing ID ASC with ID DESC I got the desired result, thanks man!! ;)

Comment: Oops, yes `DESC` - with my test table it was easier to check ascending order and I forgot to change it on copy&paste ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The `case` statement is wrong it should be as

```
SELECT * FROM question 
ORDER BY case when id = '7000' then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: and after end i can leave LIMIT ?

Comment: Yes you can add the limit after the `end`

Comment: this show result, but doesn't show the new question, in short this query order all starting from that ID... but i don't want this.. i want that 7000 is the first and after new question for example with id 7100 7099 7098 ...

Comment: yes man, i want 7000 on first and the rest normal in descending order

Comment: Check the answer from VolkerK , this should do the job.

Comment: yes i'm trying and it seems to work, thanks for your time, I up vote you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN id = '7000' then 0 else 1 END as Y FROM question ORDER BY Y
```